# How to save query results into a Hive table, in Dataproc cluster, using `.saveAsTable()`?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, hive, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a query results I am trying to write into a Hive table which is on GCP, and pointing to GCS bucket path, but when I execute the `saveAsTable()` method, its failing with following error .

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 
 aborted.org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:226)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:154)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:225)
```

Here is my code:

```scala
  sparkSession.sql(eiSqlQuery)
      .repartition("col_1")
      .write
      .mode(if(AppConfig.isHistoryLoad) Overwrite else Append)
      .partitionBy("col_2")
      .saveAsTable("hive_schema.hive_table_name")
```

I have also tried to pass the parquet path instead of `saveAsTable`
and also create the table first and tried `insertInto` as well, all failing with the following error.

What are my other options here?

Comment: May you share `hive_schema.hive_table_name` table definition and SQL query? Also, exception stack trace seems to be incomplete, may you update your question with a full stack trace including all `caused by` exceptions in casual chain into it?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a `SparkSession` with Hive enabled, for example:

```scala
// Scala
val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("Spark Hive Example")
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()
```

then you should be able to create Hive tables, for example (note the `USING hive` part in the SQL):

```scala
// Scala
sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (key INT, value STRING) USING hive")
```

then you can save dataframe into the table:

```scala
// Scala
df.write.partitionBy("key").format("hive").saveAsTable("my_table")
```

see [Spark Hive Tables](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-hive-tables.html) and the [example code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/hive/SparkHiveExample.scala).